# Using Angular UpgradeComponent

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade

I'm trying to use [UpgradeComponent](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeComponent) in order to use Angular 1 library ([ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid)) in my Angular 4 application.

My steps:

1. Create a new directive:

   ```
   import {
   Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, OnInit, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, 
   DoCheck,


   OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter, Inject
   } from '@angular/core';
   import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

   @Directive({selector: 'ui-grid'})
   export class UiGridDirective extends UpgradeComponent implements OnInit,                 OnChanges, DoCheck,
     OnDestroy {

   @Input() data: {};
   @Output() onUpdate: EventEmitter<{}>;

   constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef, @Inject(Injector)                 
    injector: Injector) {
       super('ui-grid', elementRef, injector);
     }

     ngOnInit() { super.ngOnInit(); }

     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { super.ngOnChanges(changes); }
     ngDoCheck() { super.ngDoCheck(); }
    ngOnDestroy() { super.ngOnDestroy(); }
   }
   ```
2. Add it to my module

   ```
    declarations: [UiGridDirective],
   ```
3. Tried import it in my index.html

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"/>
   ```
4. Got this erors:

Before step 3:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[$injector]: 
  StaticInjectorError[$injector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector!
```

After step 3:

[image]

Any idea how I can use this AngularJS library in my Angular 4 application?